# text color in div with filter brightness background

Tags: jquery, html, css, filter, brightness

i have child div text problem.
here is code.

```
<div style="background-image:url(http://imgnews.naver.net/image/001/2014/07/01/PAP20140701204901034_P2_99_20140701204206.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:    cover; filter:brightness(0.7); -webkit-filter:brightness(0.7);">

     <div>
         <h2>this is text.</h2>                      
     </div>

</div>
```

and this is code output image with filter:brightness.

[image]

but i want this.

[image]

how can i fix this problem?

how can childnode text be white with filter:brightness?

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/71/71930e9ea00a94c6a695b59e1441fc3cf451d3ab35a5c22ea74e69eb8b64a395.jpg

Comment: yes. like this. how can i do this??

Comment: as in the picture add text shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `filter` is effected down to all the descendants, we can't even override that property in the child element (`h2`). So we have a workaround here by rendering the background in a pseudo-element instead. That way the `filter` won't be effected down to all the descendants of the `div`:

**HTML**:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div>
     <h2>this is text.</h2>                      
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div > h2 {
  color:white;    
}
div.container {
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
div.container:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background-image:url(http://imgnews.naver.net/image/001/2014/07/01/PAP20140701204901034_P2_99_20140701204206.jpg); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover; 
  filter:brightness(0.7); 
  -webkit-filter:brightness(0.7);    
  left:0;top:0;bottom:0;right:0; 
  z-index:-1;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5ek4/1/).

Answer (score -1):

use css "[rgba](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/)" for color background or use the following code for image background

```
<div>
     <div>
         <h2>this is text.</h2>                      
     </div>

</div>


div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: -2px -1px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```